# Water flow sensor unable to get readings

Tags: sensors, arduino-nano, electronics

I connected my "arduino(nano)" to "water flow sensor" and wrote a code which simply prints the readings like 0-1023 and tested it. First i got the readings but now i'm not getting it.

My code looks something like this.

```
void setup(){
 Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop(){
 int vla=analogRead(2);
 Serial.println(vla);
 delay(1500);
}
```

and my connection.

> Sensor to Supply module
>  
>   Vcc -->  5v 
>   Gnd -->  Gnd
>
> Sensor to Arduino(Nano)
>   Sig --> D2

Comment: Also asked at http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=501527

Comment: posting details about your exact flow sensor and library being used along with your schematic and full code may get you better answers; I have used water flow sensors to a good extent for some prototypes but cant answer your question without better details since many people around simply down vote answers without understanding the question and the intent of the person who answered :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sensor to Arduino(Nano)
>   Sig --> D2

Your connections are wrong.

```
int vla=analogRead(2);
```

is reading from analog channel 2, which is pin A2 on your Nano, not D2

D2 is not an analog pin and thus you can't use it with `analogRead()`.

Comment: I tried it but i'm getting only junk value, i even tried adding a pullup.

Comment: i think its 16 for a2 and 2 for d2

Comment: Use A0, A1, A2 and so on for analog pins. To avoid any confusion. For example: int vla=analogRead(A2);

Comment: "i think its 16 for a2 and 2 for d2". `analogRead(A2)`, `analogRead(2)`, and `analogRead(16)` all do the same thing. See the source code: https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/1.8.4/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/wiring_analog.c#L38-L55

Comment: But @Jot is right, `analogRead(A2)` makes the intent of the code the most clear.

Comment: Okay. Now it's clear.